# Optimize a mysql like query

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I added the jquery autocomplete plugin to my places textfield to help users better select a location.  What I didn't realize before building is that the query would be very slow.

```
select * from `geoplanet_places` where name LIKE "%San Diego%" AND (place_type = "County" OR place_type = "Town")
```

The query above took 1.18 seconds.  Then I tried adding indexes for `name` and `place_type` but that only slowed it down (1.93s).

**Is there a way to optimize this query or is there another technique to speed up the query.**

This geoplanet_places table has 437,715 rows (mysql)

```
CREATE TABLE `geoplanet_places` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `woeid` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `parent_woeid` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `place_type` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `ancestry` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `activity_count` int(11) default '0',
  `activity_count_updated_at` datetime default NULL,
  `bounding_box` blob,
  `slug` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_geoplanet_places_on_woeid` (`woeid`),
  KEY `index_geoplanet_places_on_ancestry` (`ancestry`),
  KEY `index_geoplanet_places_on_parent_woeid` (`parent_woeid`),
  KEY `index_geoplanet_places_on_slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `index_geoplanet_places_on_name` (`name`),
  KEY `index_geoplanet_places_on_place_type` (`place_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5652569 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

EXPLAIN

```
id 1
select_type SIMPLE
table geoplanet_places
type    ALL
possible_keys   index_geoplanet_places_on_place_type
key NULL
key_len NULL
ref NULL
rows    441273
Extra   Using where
```

Comment: please post the output of `EXPLAIN select * from geoplanet_places where name LIKE "%San Diego%" AND (place_type = "County" OR place_type = "Town")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch the storage engine of the table to `MyISAM` to take advantage of full text indexing.

The `name` index wont help you unless you change the like to `LIKE 'San Diego%'` which can do a **prefix** search on the index

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the leading '%' in your where-like clause, so it becomes: where name like "San Diego%". For auto complete, this seems a reasonable limitation (assumes that the user starts typing correct characters) that should speed up the query significantly, as MySql will be able to use an existing index (index_geoplanet_places_on_name).